# Toggle between pages with storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I made a simple `if` condition and if it returns `YES` then I want to pass between two `UIViewControllers`, and I can't find the way to do that 
without using a `UIButton`.

How can I do that?

Comment: you should check some basic tutorial & reference for objective c. its very basic question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the method you're looking for is [`performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier%3asender%3a).

Don't forget to give your segue an identifier in the storyboard.

Comment: I tried this: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gonext" sender:self]; and i get an error: libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: `NSException` doesn't tell me anything other than "it crashed". Read past it a little, and it should tell you why it crashed (perhaps "unrecognized selector sent to instance …"). Post your code. Did you implement `prepareForSegue:sender:`? If so, post that in addition to the code where you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`